# Passing Xml output from Stored Procedure to AJAX client (web browser) with least overhead (memory, processing time) due to the Asp.Net middle tier?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, ado.net

I am using JQuery to perform async calls to a WebService written in C#. The WebService invokes a Stored Procedure (located in a SQL Server Database). The stored procedure returns results as XML (I use 'for xml' in the procedure to retrieve the result as XML).

**The question is**: How can I place the XML returned by the stored procedure (that is streamed by SQL Server) on to the HTTP Response stream of the WebService with the least amount of memory and processing time usage.

At the moment, my WebService returns XmlDocument object.I would like to know if there is a way to reduce the overhead of creation of XmlDocument or DataSet Objects, which consume both memory and processor time.

**Ideal solution would be:**
Connect the result stream pipe from SQL Server to the HTTP Response stream pipe. This way, whatever is coming from SQL Server will get to the client without the content being touched. No new objects are created (like DataSet, XmlDocument) and XmlParsing is avoided while creating XmlDocuments. Thus keeping the memory and processing footprint to the least. Also, whether the XML returned by the procedure is small or very large, since streams are used, memory usage will not grow (which is the case is XmlDocuments are created).

**My reduced c# webservice method:**

```
public XmlDocument GetXmlDataFromDB()
{
    string connStr = System.Convert.ToString(
            System.Web.Compilation.ConnectionStringsExpressionBuilder.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString"),
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("stp_GetXmlData", conn);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    conn.Open();

    XmlReader xmlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteXmlReader();

    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        ds.ReadXml(xmlReader);
    }

    conn.Close();

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.InnerXml = ds.GetXml();

    return xmlDoc;
}
```

Any suggestions to improve the performance of the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you don't need DataSet, SqlDataAdapter and InnerXml

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
...

var reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
if (reader.Read())
 doc.Load(reader);
```

Alternatively you can use `reader.ReadOuterXml()` to get xml as string,without constructing a document.

Also you can think of using [WCF Services for ASP.NET AJAX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412167.aspx)

Comment: Thanks George. reader.ReadOuterXml() does the needful. Are there any more points of improving the performance for the task mentioned?

Comment: As for performance tuning, it's generally infeasible without a profile of a real system.

Answer (score 2):

Obligatory warning:

> "We should forget about small
>   efficiencies, say about 97% of the
>   time: premature optimization is the
>   root of all evil" - Donald Knuth

Having said that, you could make SQL Server return a string instead of an `xml` type, like:

```
; with Query(XmlColumn) as
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    YourTable
        for xml auto
        )
select  cast(XmlColumn as varchar(max)) as StringColumn
from    Query
```

The `with` construct gives a name to the `for xml` result.  You can stream the resulting `varchar(max)` column back to the client with [`Response.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  This would avoid any parsing or object construction in the ASP.NET middle tier.

Comment: converting xml to string would result in larger data passed from sql server to the client

Comment: @George Polevoy: I don't think so, an XML data type is also transmitted as a string.  The difference is in how ADO.NET deserializes it on the client side.

Comment: Above 90% of the queries in my application don't really need any operation in the ASP.Net Layer (except for data validations for securing the app). Even a small optimization seems to reap in significant gains in handling heavy load situations. There is cost pressure on the hardware and hence optimizing every possible point is must for me.

Comment: @Andomar, without changing anything in the stored procedure, in my webservice I can read the data through a DataReader as string. How different is this from your solution above?

Comment: @Pradeep: Not 100% sure, but if you can read it as a string, I think it will not be deserialized into an XML object.  So that would have identical (or even better) performance as my solution.

Comment: Thank You. I will test the solutions I have here and post my results. Thanks for all you help.